# Firebase Remove data from array giving java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: android, firebase

I am please to post this here because I have been wasting 2 days in this error. Actually me have to work with firebase and I don't have much command. I am adding data into array like this method

```
 public void addNewNode(String id, String name,String price){
    HashMap<String, String> names = new HashMap<>();
    names.put("menu_extra_item_id", id);
    names.put("menu_extra_item_name",name);
    names.put("menu_extra_item_price",price);
    names.put("menu_extra_item_quantity",inc_dec_tv.getText().toString());
    ExtraItem.add(names);
    mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(new 
    CalculationModel(userId,restaurant_menu_item_id,
            name_,price_,"1","0",ExtraItem));
}
```

data is adding perfectly but when me need to remove a specific node it gives me a massive trouble. I am trying this code to remove node

```
 public void deleteNewNode(final String id){
    dataArray = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference query = mDatabase;
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //child is each element in the finished list

                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) 
                child.getValue();

                dataArray.add(map.get("extraItem")) ;

                int sizeArray = dataArray.size();
                for (int i =0;i<dataArray.size();i++){

                    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
                    map2.put("value", dataArray.get(i));
                   // String mapVal = String.valueOf(map2);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map2);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = 
                        jsonObject.getJSONArray("value");

                        for (int j = 0;j<jsonArray.length();j++){
                            JSONObject allJsonObject = 
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

                            String val1 = 
                            allJsonObject.optString("menu_extra_item_id");

                            int sizeBeforRemove =  ExtraItem.size();

                            if(val1.equalsIgnoreCase(id)){

                                int some = i;
                                ExtraItem.remove(i);

                                String extraItemRemaining = 
                               ExtraItem.toString();
                              int sizeAfterRemove =  ExtraItem.size();

                                mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(new 
                            CalculationModel(userId,restaurant_menu_item_id,
                                        name_,price_,"1","0",ExtraItem));


                            }

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

`ExtraItem` is a grobal array initialized but when I call `deleteNode` method this gives error

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1                                                                               at java.util.ArrayList.remove

also here is I am calling both methods.

```
if (checkBox != null) {
    checkBox.toggle();
    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
        item.setCheckBoxIsChecked(true);    
        addNewNode(item.getExtra_item_id(),item.getChild_item_name(), item.getChild_item_price());                                
    } else {

        item.setCheckBoxIsChecked(false);                       
        deleteNewNode(item.getExtra_item_id());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove second element when you have only one item in the list. 
`ArrayList.remove(1)` removes second element.

Comment: what is the remedy to avoid this?